# How to have multiple conditions with OR in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a cloudFormation and I wish to allow my lambda assume a role if the role applies to at least one of the two conditions:

1. It has a specific tag.
2. It comes from a specific account.

In order to do so, I wrote execution role for the lambda with the first condition (and this seems to be running ok):

```
"Condition": {
       "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
             "aws:TagKeys": "MonteCarloData"
       }
},
```

However, according to this documentation- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html

It seems like the conditions always have AND between them.
So not sure how can I and the second condition and accomplish the OR operator.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: Lambda does not support tag-based conditions. Can you clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: this is the condition for the lambda execution role. I want to allow my lambda to assume a role.

Comment: Just make two separate IAM policy statements. One with the first conditions, second with the second condition.

Comment: I guess this will work. thought perhaps there is something more elegant.
Thanks!

Comment: Two conditions in the same statement are always `and`. You can't place `or` between them.

Comment: yeah, so it seems. 
In any case, for the second condition I think I need some limitation on the resource to make sure it's coming from the other account.

Comment: If you don't mind, I can provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: sure. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Two conditions in a single IAM policy statement are [evaluated using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval) `AND`:

> If your policy has multiple condition operators or multiple keys attached to a single condition operator, the conditions are **evaluated using a logical AND**.

Therefore, you could create **two** separate IAM [statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_statement.html). One for the first conditions, and the second one for the second condition.